How to prevent Hibernate 6.4 from storing @Column(columnDefinition = 'text') fields as Large Objects (LOBs) in PostgreSQL?
After updating from Hibernate 5.6 to 6.4, I noticed that fields annotated with @Column(columnDefinition = "text") are now stored as references to Large Objects in PostgreSQL. Instead of storing the data directly in the table as text, Hibernate is using the pg_largeobject and pg_largeobject_metadata tables.
The affected fields are of types that implement Externalizable, and the data stored in these fields is JSON. Previously, these fields were simply stored as text columns in the database without involving Large Object storage.
Is there a way to configure Hibernate 6.4 to store these fields in a text column directly, without using Large Object storage, and without modifying the model classes?
Here’s an anonymized example field in one of my entities:
@Column(columnDefinition = "text")
private MyExternalizableType jsonData;

where MyExternalizableType implements Externalizable.
Any guidance on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated!
In Hibernate 5.6, these fields were stored directly as text in the database, which is what I expected to continue in Hibernate 6.4. After the update, however, Hibernate started storing them as references to Large Objects in the pg_largeobject and pg_largeobject_metadata tables, rather than as plain text in the table itself.
I’ve reviewed the model and configuration, but I haven’t yet found a way to force Hibernate 6.4 to store these fields as simple text without modifying the model classes.


Is there a way to configure Hibernate 6.4 to store these fields in a text column directly, without using Large Object storage.

The simplest way, if you want to convert this MyExternalizableType to json|jsonb|text for storage.
Is to use the io.hypersistence:hypersistence-utils-hibernate-xx library.

Note: io.hypersistence:hypersistence-utils-hibernate-63 with hibernate-core:6.4.

@Column(name = "json_data", columnDefinition = "text")
@Type(JsonType.class) // import io.hypersistence.utils.hibernate.type.json.JsonType;
private MyExternalizableType jsonData;




and without modifying the model classes?

The Externalizable interface may not necessary in such cases(I think).
